# JQuery Ajax not interacting with MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm attempting to make a very basic browser MMORPG with php, ajax, and jquery. However the webpages do not seem to be interacting with the MySQL server correctly.

Here is my php class that defines some SQL functions:

```
<?php
class Db {
protected static $connection;

public function connect() {
    if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
        $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); 
        self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }
    if(self::$connection === false) {
        return false;
    }
    return self::$connection;
}

public function query($query) {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    $result = $connection -> query($query);
    return $result;
}

public function select($query) {
    $rows = array();
    $result = $this -> query($query);
    if($result === false) {
        return false;
    }
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}

public function error() {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    return $connection -> error;
}

public function quote($value) {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    return "'" . $connection -> real_escape_string($value) . "'";
}
public function close()
{
    mysqli_close(self::$connection);
}
}
?>
```

Along with the config.ini it references:

```
[database]
username = root
password = ***
dbname = ***
```

(password and database name have been omitted but I've checked that they are correct.)

Here is my validation.php file that the login uses:

```
<?php
include 'DbClass.php';
$db = new Db();
$name= = $db -> quote($_POST['user_name']);
$pass=md5($db -> quote($_POST['password']));
$rows = $db -> select("select * from players where name=" . $name . " and password=" . $pass);
if($rows)
{
   echo json_encode("1");
}
else
{
   echo json_encode("0");
}

?>
```

And here is the login javascript file with the functions that are called on my index page.

```
function login()
{
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);  
        $.ajax({
            url : 'scripts/php/validation.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : { user_name:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) { 
          if(data == 1)
                {
                        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
                        { 
                          $(this).html('Logging in...').addClass('alert alert-success').fadeTo(900,1,
                          function()
                          { 
                              buildPage();
                          });

                        });
            }
            else
            {
               $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
                    { 
                      $(this).html('Your login details are incorrect').addClass('alert alert-danger').fadeTo(900,1);
                    });      
            }
        }
    });
}

function registration()
{
      document.getElementById("registerBox").innerHTML = "<form class='form-horizontal' method='post' action='' id='register_form'>" +
                      "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6 column'><div class='control-group'>" + 
                        "<label class='control-label' for='username'>Username</label><div class=''controls'>" + 
                          "<input type='text' id='registerUsername' placeholder='Username'>" +
                        "</div></div>" +
                      "<div class='control-group'>" +
                        "<label class='control-label' for='password'>Password</label>" +
                        "<div class='controls'>" +
                          "<input type='password' id='registerPassword' placeholder='Password'>" +
                        "</div><br></div>" +
                        "<div class='control-group'>" +
                        "<label class='control-label' for='rePassword'>Retype Password</label>" +
                        "<div class='controls'>" +
                          "<input type='password' id='rePassword' placeholder='Retype Password'>" +
                        "</div><br></div><div id='registerMsgbox'></div></div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-3 column'>" +
                        "<b><u>Choose a Class</b></u><br><div id='characters'></div>" +
                        "</div></div>" +
                      "<div class='control-group'>" +
                        "<div class='controls'>" +
                          "<input name='Submit' type='button' onclick='javascript:register()' value='Register' class='btn btn-success'/>" +
                        "</div></div></form>";
       $.ajax({
        url : 'scripts/php/getCharacters.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {type:'classes'
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) {              
           buildClasses(data);
        }
    });
}

function loginPage()
{
      document.getElementById("registerBox").innerHTML = "<form class='form-horizontal' method='post' action='' id='login_form'>" +
                      "<div class='control-group'>" +
                        "<label class='control-label' for='username'>Username</label>" +
                        "<div class='controls'>" +
                          "<input type='text' id='username' placeholder='Username'></div></div>" +
                      "<div class='control-group'> " +
                        "<label class='control-label' for='password'>Password</label>" +
                        "<div class='controls'>" +
                          "<input type='password' id='password' placeholder='Password'>" +
                        "</div><br>" +
                           "<div id='msgbox'></div></div>" +
                      "<div class='control-group'>" +
                        "<div class='controls'>" +
                          "<input name='Submit' type='button' onclick='javascript:login()' value='Login' class='btn btn-success'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                          "<input name='Submit' type='button' onclick='javascript:registration()' value='Register' class='btn btn-success'/>" +
                        "</div>" +
                      "</div>" +
                    "</form></div><div class='modal-footer'></div>";
}

function buildClasses(data)
{
    var characterDiv = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        characterDiv += "<div class='characterBox'><input type='radio' name='radioClasses' value='" + data[i].id + "'><img src='media/characters/heroTiles/" + data[i].pic + ".png'>" + data[i].name + "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML = characterDiv;
}
```

I also have a registration script that doesn't do anything to the database either, but I figure for the sake of having less code covering the page that posting that probably isn't required, since I assume the issue is somewhere in my database function class or one of these other places.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot extract the problem from the description... What is it?

Comment: @sitilge The query results are not finding their way back to the page (and in the case of my registration page, the new information is not being added to the database.)

Comment: What are the results?

Comment: @sitilge Well in the case of the login scripts, the results should be the number of rows that match the entered username and a md5 hash of the entered password. But the problem is that there are no results.

Comment: Could you `var_dump($results);` ?

Comment: @sitilge I assume you mean var_dump($rows); because $results is not a variable, I've added that in under the select function call in my validation.php file but it doesn't seem to be doing anything, I've checked in the developer console, but it's blank. Where should I look for the information this spits out?

Comment: If the page is blank that could be a good reason to check `error.log`

Comment: @sitilge `error.log`? What is error.log?

Comment: A file where webserver writes error events. Also be as explicit as you can - "but it doesn't seem to be doing anything" doesn't help. Is it dumping an empty array, string, is it not dumping anything?

Comment: @sitilge Well there is no error.log file. This project started from scratch so unless I had made an error.log file there wouldn't be one. I think the issue with var_dump is I don't know what it's supposed to be doing. I assume it would output the contents of the variable somewhere, but I don't know where that would be.

Comment: Better read this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Comment: @sitilge Well I found the apache error log, although that link you provided just explains what an error log is, which wasn't incredibly helpful... But the apache error log does not contain any information about php script errors or MySQL issues, it just says when the apache service was started or stopped. I think you misunderstood me when I said the google chrome dev console was blank. I did not mean the page was blank. Do you understand what kind of issue I'm having?

Answer (score 0):

why do you think that it is not interacting with mysql? Have you tried using Browsers developer console (network page) to see if the request is being sent?
Could you post some screenshots of those requests?

Comment: If you are referring to the chrome developer console, it remains blank. And when I say "not interacting" I include something being wrong with the request in the first place that prevents it from being sent. Which is why I included the scripts and functions.

Comment: Ah, the network page. I see which tab you mean now, I can't post a screenshot of it because I don't have 10 reputation however this is the link to the image: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bDQCX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, It turns out it was caused by a conflicting MySQL service on the same port. *facepalm*
Sorry if I wasted your time. We all make dumb mistakes every once in a while...